# Pentaho Data Integration - Sometimes Variables are Picked Up, Sometimes They Are Not

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a job, let's call it `Job A`.
I have another job, let's call it `Job B`.
I have a transformation, let's call it `Transform A`.

`Job A` calls `Job B` and `Job B` calls `Transformation A`.
Inside of `Job B`, I am using a Set Variables step to set some variable values, which I am then passing off to `Transformation A`.

Sometimes `Transformation A` receives the variables, but sometimes it doesn't.

Is there any suggested way to pass the variables from `Job B` to `Transformation A` or any guidelines to follow? Perhaps I am not setting something up correctly.

**Edit #1:**

`Transformation A` is using a SQL query where I am passing through variables.

`Job A` is also running `Job C`, `Job D, ..., Job Z` in parallel. In all ~25 jobs, they are all calling `Transformation A` at the end.

Comment: All variables set in a job are automatically accessible by any of its descendants (sub jobs or sub transformations). No need to set anything up. So there's something wrong with the way the variables are being set in Job B. Maybe a couple screenshots will help, including a screenshot of your Job B set variables step and what scope those variables are defined in.

Comment: What is the scope of your variables? If they are parent job or root the diffrent jobs (B till Z) might interfere with each other.

We also sometimes have issue if variables with the same name are hardcoded in the properties of the transformation A. Try removing the default value if present there and see if it fies the issue.